# Using emit to build a Kotlin flow runs indefinitely and doesnt complete

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, eventstoredb

I use a java library with which I can subscribe to events from my eventstore db.

I can create a subscription according to the following `SubscirptionListener`

```
public abstract class SubscriptionListener {
    public void onEvent(Subscription subscription, ResolvedEvent event) {
    }

    public void onError(Subscription subscription, Throwable throwable) {
    }

    public void onCancelled(Subscription subscription) {
    }
}
```

I would like to emit `ResolvedEvent`s as part of a flow each time the subscription is triggered. However, the call to `emit` doesn't finish.

```
    fun flowSubscriptionListener(
        streamName: String,
        options: SubscribeToStreamOptions = SubscribeToStreamOptions.get(),
        onError: (subscription: Subscription?, throwable: Throwable) -> Unit = { _, _ -> },
        onCancelled: (subscription: Subscription) -> Unit = { _ -> }
    ): Flow<ResolvedEvent> {
        return flow {
            val listener = object : SubscriptionListener() {
                override fun onEvent(subscription: Subscription, event: ResolvedEvent) {
                    logger.info {
                        "Received event ${event.originalEvent.streamRevision}@${event.originalEvent.streamId}"
                    }

                    runBlocking {
                        logger.info { "emitting event" }
                        this@flow.emit(event)
                        logger.info { "Event emitted" }
                    }
                }

                override fun onError(subscription: Subscription?, throwable: Throwable) {
                    logger.error {
                        "Received error with message: ${throwable.message ?: "No message"} on subscription ${subscription?.subscriptionId}"
                    }
                    onError(subscription, throwable)
                }

                override fun onCancelled(subscription: Subscription) {
                    logger.debug { "Subscription ${subscription.subscriptionId} cancelled" }
                    onCancelled(subscription)
                }
            }
            client.subscribeToStream(streamName, listener).await()
        }.buffer(10)
    }
```

I have a sample setup where I await a flow with three events

```
flowSubscriptionListener(
            streamName = "SampleTournament-adb517b8-62e9-4305-b3b6-c1e7193a6d19",
        ).map {
            it.event.eventType
        }.collect {
            println(it)
        }
```

However, I receive no events at all. The console output shows me that invocation of `emit` never terminates.

```
[grpc-default-executor-1] INFO lib.eventstoredb.wrapper.EskWrapperEsdb - Received event 0@SampleTournament-adb517b8-62e9-4305-b3b6-c1e7193a6d19
[grpc-default-executor-1] INFO lib.eventstoredb.wrapper.EskWrapperEsdb - emitting event
```

I am expecting the logging of `"Event emitted"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to wrap callback-based API, you should use [callbackFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) instead. It supports concurrent emissions, which I think is likely your problem here.

Also, it will properly handle the cancellation of the subscription when the flow itself is cancelled (via `awaitClose()`).

Here is one way to do it:

```kotlin
fun EventStoreDBClient.flowSubscription(
    streamName: String,
    options: SubscribeToStreamOptions = SubscribeToStreamOptions.get(),
): Flow<ResolvedEvent> = callbackFlow {
    val listener = object : SubscriptionListener() {
        override fun onEvent(subscription: Subscription, event: ResolvedEvent) {
            logger.info { "Received event ${event.originalEvent.streamRevision}@${event.originalEvent.streamId}" }
            logger.info { "Emitting event" }
            trySendBlocking(event)
            logger.info { "Event emitted" }
        }

        override fun onError(subscription: Subscription?, throwable: Throwable) {
            logger.error {
                "Received error with message: ${throwable.message ?: "No message"} on subscription ${subscription?.subscriptionId}"
            }
            close(throwable)
        }

        override fun onCancelled(subscription: Subscription) {
            logger.debug { "Subscription ${subscription.subscriptionId} cancelled" }
            close()
        }
    }
    val subscription = subscribeToStream(streamName, listener, options).await()
    awaitClose {
        subscription.stop()
    }
}.buffer(10)
```

Note that I also converted it to an extension function on `EventStoreDBClient`, which seems appropriate here. And I removed the error/cancellation callbacks because `Flow` already handles those (you can put them back if you need them)